# Expression Syntax Error e2188, C++, Embarcadero, Count_If,

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, stl

I am trying to run a `count_if` over a `vector<int>` in C++ Embarcadero Seattle.

The vector was successfully constructed and instantiated with a handful of values, some odd, some even.

I get 'E2188 Expression Syntax' error message over the lambda in this statement

```
int oddCounter = count_if(v.begin(), v.end(), [](int i){return i%2 != 0;});
```

I have checked a number of sources and I can't find anything wrong with the syntax.  Any ideas?

Comment: Are you compiling in (at least) C++11 mode?

Comment: Many thanks Angew.  That pointed me in the right direction.  My knowledge of compilers and settings is very limited.  I have managed to compile it by switching to a 64-bit Windows target for now.  I am guessing there is a more direct method - a compiler flag that will do the same for 32 bit.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks Angew. The lambda now compiles. I presume C++ 11 has now been included after switching to a 64-bit Windows target.